# Background smaller than containing div (of variable size)

Tags: css

I want to create a slightly indented background behind embedded media, for which the size varies. It should look like this:

[image: what it should look like]

See how the green background is slightly indented from the top and bottom of the youtube video? I have gotten everything else to show up as I want, I just can't figure out how to position the background slightly inside of the embedded media item. Especially since I know the media item size will change.

You can see what I have so far on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thwackukulele/9qeP3/).

Comment: If you're most of the way there, consider including a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) in your question so your existing work can be tweaked instead of rewritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple give negative margin like

```
iframe { margin-top: -10px; }
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qeP3/3/)

Comment: Thank you! This works. So easy, but I never would have thought of it.

Comment: I'd like to add that I needed to apply a positive margin to the outer div to keep everything lined up. So, .frame { margin: -50px; } .framewrap { margin: 50px; }

Comment: @danapaige, I dont understand. Is that another problem? The technique I showed is a very simple trick and can be user, even if the outer container has margin on it.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
.framewrap {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #edf3dd;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
}
.frame {
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -320px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9qeP3/1/

Comment: That sort of works, but the media size will vary. Users will be embedding youtube videos, facebook photos, their own uploaded photos, etc. So the layout needs to be fluid and adapt to any media size. Could I use % instead of px?

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I am no jQuery guru but I found a solution for your problem.

```
// Gets the height of the video
var dynHeight = $('iframe').height();

// Removes 40 pixels from the height of the container sets it to a trimmed variable
var trimmed = dynHeight - 40;

// Sets the height of the container to the trimmed variable
$('.framewrap').height(trimmed);
```

Then in your CSS file use negative margin to get the desired effect.

```
.frame { margin-top: -20px }
```

Here is the [JSFiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/9qeP3/2/)